# Shouldn't this return me an error? Is this a bad practice?

Tags: go, if-statement, testing

I wrote the following code in Golang:

```
func Test_HandlerError_EdpointsReturnError(t *testing.T) {
    assert := assert.New(t)
    objExpected := BodyForTest{ID: 2}

    endpointInternalErr := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (interface{}, int, error) {
        return nil, 0, internalerrors.ErrInternal
    }
    endpointDomainErr := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (interface{}, int, error) {
        return nil, 0, errors.New("Domain Error")
    }
    endpointObjAndStatus := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (interface{}, int, error) {
        return objExpected, 201, nil
    }

    handlerFuncToInternalErr := HandlerError(endpointInternalErr)
    handlerFuncToDomainErr := HandlerError(endpointDomainErr)
    handlerFuncToObjAndStatus := HandlerError(endpointObjAndStatus)
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
    res := httptest.NewRecorder()

    handlerFuncToInternalErr.ServeHTTP(res, req)
    handlerFuncToDomainErr.ServeHTTP(res, req)
    handlerFuncToObjAndStatus.ServeHTTP(res, req)

    if http.StatusInternalServerError == res.Code {
        // INTERNAL ERROR
        assert.Equal(http.StatusInternalServerError, res.Code)
        assert.Contains(res.Body.String(), internalerrors.ErrInternal.Error())
    }
    if http.StatusBadRequest == res.Code {
        // DOMAIN ERROR
        assert.Equal(http.StatusBadRequest, res.Code)
        assert.Contains(res.Body.String(), "Domain Error")
    }
    if http.StatusCreated == res.Code {
        assert.Equal(http.StatusCreated, res.Code)
        objReturned := BodyForTest{}
        json.Unmarshal(res.Body.Bytes(), &objReturned)
        assert.Equal(objExpected, objReturned)
    }
}
```

And as you can see in the end, there's a lot of `Ifs`, to make tests only, each if is for testing a different thing. The thing is, I got this from a teacher who wrote a similar code, the only difference is that, instead of having it all on the same func with `Ifs` as I did, he did one func for each test.
When I wrote it I was expecting that it'd work, because somehow it made sense to test it all at one func only, and it did worked! But then I read it again and noticed that on my `Ifs`, I'm comparing different types of http Status with the same var `res`, so that's what got me, how come they all go okay when they're all comparing itselves to the same variable?

Also, another doubt that came, is that if this what I'm doing could be considered a bad practice on coding, because that instead of having multiple funcs for each type of test, I'm testing it all at only one function, and I'm also checking if the requirement is matched on the `if`, so then I can test it with the func `assert` from package `testify`, but it'll always be ok because if the `if` is true, then the `assert.Equal` func will work. Is this wrong?

Firstly my code was written with `if` and `else ifs`, but I noticed that, besides it was working, wasn't ideal because the test was obviously stopping at the first if since it was being matched, so it wouldn't even go to the others, so then I changed it all to multiple `Ifs`, but that's when I noticed it could go wrong, considering I was comparing different entries with one var. But somehow it's working. But why? Shouldn't it not be working?

Comment: What _is_ bad is the use of assert instead of proper t.Error.

Comment: Well instead `if .. else if` a `switch` statement would be preferable. But imo the main problem is that `res.Code` could be `http.StatusInternalServerError` in all situations, even when you expected it to be, say, `http.StatusBadRequest`. Your test would succeed in spite of the wrong status codes being returned.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The presence of if conditions in tests implies that you do not understand what is happening in the test and allow for different scenarios. The test should be linear and unambiguous. The best way to make a test unambiguous is either to use table driven tests (https://dave.cheney.net/2019/05/07/prefer-table-driven-tests), or to divide one test into several subtests via t.Run (by the way, this looks great in table driven tests too).

Your code doesn't work, so here's a non-working example solution:

```golang
func Test_HandlerError_EdpointsReturnError(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run(`internal`, func(t *testing.T) {
        handler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (interface{}, int, error) {
            return nil, 0, internalerrors.ErrInternal
        }
        handler.ServeHTTP(res, req)

        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/", nil)
        require.NoError(t, err)
        res := httptest.NewRecorder()

        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusInternalServerError, res.Code)
        assert.Contains(t, res.Body.String(), internalerrors.ErrInternal.Error())
    })

    t.Run(`domain`, func(t *testing.T) {

    })
    t.Run(`success`, func(t *testing.T) {

    })
}
```